# mac sed add new lines before the matched content

Tags: macos, shell, awk, sed

We need to add comments in our ios project, the OC method declare like `- (void)...`, I want to write a script to help me to do this.
In the source files, I want add comments before the method declaration with `//method name: ....`, but I'm not good at shell ...

For example,

```
- (id)initWithWindow:(UIWindow *)window;

- (id)initWithView:(UIView *)view;

- (void)show:(BOOL)animated;

- (void)hide:(BOOL)animated;

- (void)hide:(BOOL)animated afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay;
```

I want to add new lines like this:

```
.
.
.
//method: - (void)hide:(BOOL)animated;
//parma: animated
- (void)hide:(BOOL)animated;

//method: - (id)initWithView:(UIView *)view;
//parma: view
- (id)initWithView:(UIView *)view;
.
.
.
```

How should I do with shell on mac?

Comment: Welcome to SO, your question is NOT clear. Please EDIT it and let us know what could be the conditions to add those lines and where they should be added? Please EDIT your post with proper details.

Comment: Sorry, I descript the situation, is it clear ? If not, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: You want the script to reorder your method definitions and delete some of them? Make sure your posted expected output is **THE** expected output you want given the input you provided and not just some vague approximation of it.

Comment: Do only the lines that start with '-' need be replaced?

Comment: Yes, maybe start with '+' or '-', I use thie `gsed 's|^[-+] (.*)\([a-zA-Z]*\)|//method: &\n//parma: \n\n&|g' filename`, but I can't get all the parameters(only the last one), do you know how ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
sed '/-/{h;s|^|//method: |;p;g;s|.*)|//parma: |;s|;$||;p;g;}' filename
```

This will print the result to the screen. You can redirect it to another file:

```
sed '/-/{h;s|^|//method: |;p;g;s|.*)|//parma: |;s|;$||;p;g;}' filename > newfile
```

Or modify the old file in place:

```
sed -i '' '/-/{h;s|^|//method: |;p;g;s|.*)|//parma: |;s|;$||;p;g;}' filename
```

This is a moderately complex sed command. If you want to understand it, I suggest you practice simpler sed commands first.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following command:

```
sed 's|^- (.*)\([a-z]*\);|//method: &\n//parma: \1\n&|g' inputfile > outputfile
```

Sample input:

```
- (id)initWithWindow:(UIWindow *)window;

- (void)hide:(BOOL)animated;

- (void)hide:(BOOL)animated afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay;
```

Sample output:

```
//method: - (id)initWithWindow:(UIWindow *)window;
//parma: window
- (id)initWithWindow:(UIWindow *)window;   

//method: - (void)hide:(BOOL)animated;
//parma: animated
- (void)hide:(BOOL)animated;

//method: - (void)hide:(BOOL)animated afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay;
//parma: delay
- (void)hide:(BOOL)animated afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay;
```

Comment: I used `gsed` on mac, it works. I use `gsed 's|^[-+] (.*)\([a-zA-Z]*\)|//method: &\n//parma: \n\n&|g'`. But can you extract the `animated` and `delay` both ? Maybe more parmas.